# Posting from apple clipboard into JTable?

Tags: java, macos, jtable

I would like to paste multiple cells from excel into `JTable`. Searching for the solution returned [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077579/learn-java/java-tip-77--enable-copy-and-paste-functionality-between-swing-s-jtables-and-excel.html) old reference:

I used this `ExcelAdapter.java` with a couple of minor changes as I wanted it to work on `Mac` and not only on `PC`. So, I had to use that.

```
KeyStroke copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK);
```

When `OS` is `Mac` and also I found out that while copying, the new line character should be `\r` and not `\n`.

There is an interesting discussion on the subject
[here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=252109).

So,  now copying from JTable into excel works fine, but with pasting I have the following problem:

The starting cell where I want to paste gets active for editing once I press the Command Key, so when I press `V` the content from the clipboard does not write into that starting cell.

So, all other cells are filled fine, but not the first one. Here is the relevant snippets of the code.

```
    public final static boolean SYSTEMISMAC=(System.getProperty("os.name")).startsWith("M");
  .... 
        if(SYSTEMISMAC) StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\r"); // For Mac
        else  StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\n"); 
         for(int i=0;st1.hasMoreTokens();i++)
         {
            rowstring=st1.nextToken();
            StringTokenizer st2=new StringTokenizer(rowstring,"\t");
            for(int j=0;st2.hasMoreTokens();j++)
            {
               value=(String)st2.nextToken();
               if (startRow+i< jTable1.getRowCount()  &&
                   startCol+j< jTable1.getColumnCount())
                  jTable1.setValueAt(value,startRow+i,startCol+j);
               System.out.println("Putting "+ value+" atrow= "+startRow+i+"column= "+startCol+j);
           }
        }
```

I can see that the program tries to get the value into the table  when `i=0` and `j=0`, but it cannot (I am guessing because the cell is already active). How to get over it?

Should I disable the activation of the cell by pressing Command (I don't think it is that useful, the user can use the mouse to select a cell, but how to disable)? I am not sure whether this problem is Mac specific (I have not checked Windows yet). If there is a better way of pasting from excel to JTable?

Comment: Determination of when a cell should become editable is normally determined by the cell editor. Are you using any special editors? If not, you could cancel any active cell editing first before updating the model

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, This is what I just figured out after I posted the question. I added
 CellEditor cellEdit=jTable1.getCellEditor(startRow, startCol);
 cellEdit.cancelCellEditing();
Before the outer loop, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Thank you, trashgod. I just did

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, as correctly pointed out by MadProgrammer, the key is to call Cell Editor and cancel any editing.
For completeness I am providing corrected snippet of the code with the corrections. It works for me

```
public final static boolean SYSTEMISMAC=(System.getProperty("os.name")).startsWith("M");  if(SYSTEMISMAC) StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\r"); // For Mac
    else  StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\n"); 
    CellEditor cellEdit=jTable1.getCellEditor(startRow, startCol);
    cellEdit.cancelCellEditing();
     for(int i=0;st1.hasMoreTokens();i++)
     {
        rowstring=st1.nextToken();
        StringTokenizer st2=new StringTokenizer(rowstring,"\t");
        for(int j=0;st2.hasMoreTokens();j++)
        {
           value=(String)st2.nextToken();
           if (startRow+i< jTable1.getRowCount()  &&
               startCol+j< jTable1.getColumnCount())
              jTable1.setValueAt(value,startRow+i,startCol+j);
           System.out.println("Putting "+ value+" atrow= "+startRow+i+"column= "+startCol+j);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with this variant on your solution. By using both \n and \r as tokenisers on line 3 below I can paste from excel or from other sources like TextEdit.

The rowstring.replace on line 7 also allows me to carry over empty cells in a two-dimensional table from excel.

Keeping in mind that on Mac, I still have to copy and paste with control + C, control + P, not command + C, command + P

```
         String trstring= (String)(system.getContents(this).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
         System.out.println("String is:"+trstring);      
         StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\n\r");
         for(int i=0;st1.hasMoreTokens();i++)
         {
            rowstring=st1.nextToken();
            rowstring = rowstring.replace("\t\t", "\t \t");
            StringTokenizer st2=new StringTokenizer(rowstring,"\t");
            for(int j=0;st2.hasMoreTokens();j++)
            {
               value=(String)st2.nextToken();
               if (startRow+i< jTable1.getRowCount()  &&
                   startCol+j< jTable1.getColumnCount())
                  jTable1.setValueAt(value,startRow+i,startCol+j);
               System.out.println("Putting "+ value+"atrow="+startRow+i+"column="+startCol+j);
           }
        }
```